# What's the use of XFL ( Uncompressed ) file in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I noticed some while "Save AS.." , it says "XFL file" "Uncompressed flash file" . What's it's use ? Why i would need it  instead of FLA ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its the new fileformat. It is nothing more as a folder with one or more xmls and stuff. The main problem about *.fla project files is that there are binary. It is difficult to work with version tools like svn or git with binary files. When everything is in ascii it is possible to merge changes from two different trees. When you`re using a fla and you have a merge conflict you have to resolve the conflict by hand.